# How to create angularjs filter which outputs HTML

Tags: angularjs

After reading [AngularJS tutorial step-9](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)
I have created my own AngularJS filter, which should convert boolean data into html.

Here is my filter code:

```
angular.module('phonecatFilters', []).filter('iconify', function () { // My custom filter
    return function (input) {
        return input ? '<i class="icon-ok"></i>' : '<i class="icon-remove"></i>';
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<dt>Infrared</dt>
  <dd>{{phone.connectivity.infrared | iconify }}"></dd>
```

The problem is that borwser displays returned value literally as:

```
<i class="icon-ok"></i>
```

not as icons (or rendered html) that should appear.

[Here is JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/942RA/3/)

I think that some sanitisation occurs during this process.

Is it possible to turn this sanitization off for this specific filter?

Also I know how to display icons by not returning HTML output from filter but rather just 'ok' or 'remove' text which I can then substitute to:

```
<i class="icon-{{phone.connectivity.infrared | iconify}}"><i>
```

but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You should use the `ng-bind-html` directive (require to import the sanitize module and js file):
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
<span ng-bind-html='phone.connectivity.infrared | iconify'></span>
```

You also need to import the CSS ([Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) I guess) to be able to see the icon when it works.

I have provided a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/g/942RA/4/).

Comment: thanks for reply but your solution is almost the same as mine with `<i class="icon-{{phone.connectivity.infrared | icon}}"><i>` and I do not use extra SPAN tag in my case.

Comment: Well it's the only way I know to output raw html with angularJS and this binding is only allowed on attributes so you don't have much choice, you can write you own directive that accept comments or elements bindings, take the source code of bind-html for a starting point: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/directive/ngBindHtml.js

Comment: A directive maybe the nicest solution here <check-icon ng:model='phone.connectivity.infrared'></check-icon> but it's not really shorter than your solution ;)

Comment: One thing to note is that you need to include the `angular-sanitize.js` file for this to work. If you want to do the same without including this extra library, you can use the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive.

Comment: angular 2.x drops `ng-html-bind-unsafe` and requires the html contents to be explicit marked as 'safe' - see: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#Example

Comment: There should be a default filter html_safe: `{{myContent | myFilter | html_safe}}`

Comment: do i need to include something for html_safe

Answer (score 17):

Unless I am reading it wrong, you are approaching in the wrong way.

I think `ng-class` is the directive you need for this job and is safer than rendering to class attribute.

In your case just add object string with the id strings as the class and the value as the evaluated expression.

```
<i ng-class="{
'icon-ok':!phone.connectivity.infrared,
'icon-remove':phone.connectivity.infrared
}"></i>'
```

On a side note, you should only use directives (built-in and custom) to manipulate html/dom and if you needed a more complex html render you should look at directive instead.

Comment: Good solution.  Or done a bit simpler:

`<i ng-class="phone.connectivity.infrared ? 'icon-ok' : 'icon-remove'"></i>`

Answer (score 12):

Try this filter

```
filter('trust', ['$sce',function($sce) {
  return function(value, type) {
    return $sce.trustAs(type || 'html', value);
  }
}]);
```

requires [angular-sanitize](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js)

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
```

[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/vikrant2mahajan/016f4852cb4a6db04fba)