# Why is this AngualrJS data binding not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templating

[How to create angularjs filter which outputs HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251581/how-to-create-angularjs-filter-which-outputs-html) has what looks like what I want, but my version isn't working yet. In my HTML I have:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="book in books | filter:query">
            {{book.title}}
            <div ng-bind-html="book.snippet"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But it is displaying the book titles only, as if the <div ng-bind-html...> was not there. The controller has all desired data, starting with:

```
$scope.books = [
        {
        'image': '/images/the_best_of_jonathans_corner_full.jpg',
        'snippet': '<p>If you read just one book from this site, <em>The Best of Jonathan\'s Corner</em> is a head taller than the others. It contains   all of the best works of theology from Jonathan\'s Corner, and there\'s a lot to dig through&mdash;but only if you want. If not, feel free to enjoy and read  as little or as much as you like.</p><p>This book is the author\'s favorite title out of all the books sold from this site.</p>',
        'title': 'The Best of Jonathan\'s Corner',
        'url': '/redirect/the_best_of_jonathans_corner.html'
        },
```

The webpage looks something like:

```
CJS Hayward

Search books:

    The Best of Jonathan's Corner
    Doxology: The Anthology
    The Luddite's Guide to Technology
```

Why is the book.title appearing but not the book.snippet? I have HTML in some of the snippets, and I would like them to render the snippet as HTML. (I can have an escaped version as {{book.snippet}}, but I'd like to know the right way to handle HTML (non-)escaping here.) All the snippets are meant to be written as strictly valid XHTML, with closing </p> tags etc.

The project is intended to be a playalong of the AngularJS phonecat tutorial.

--UPDATE--

Thank you, @ppa; I've edited the source file to include:

```
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
```

The controllers.js now begins:

```
'use strict';

var authorApp = angular.module('authorApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

And AngularJS is not repeating anything (and I don't see anything new in the console.logs):

```
CJS Hayward

Search books:

    {{book.title}}
```

What else should I be including? The app is presently at http://new.cjsh.name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a brief look at your code in the developer tools, I can see that you are using the angular-sanitize.js of Angular version 1.3(beta5). But your angular.js script is in version 1.2. I am guessing that the problem lies in this version mismatch. Please try to use the angular.js script from the same 1.3 version and see if this works. You can find it [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/).

Answer (score 1):

In order for the [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive to work, the $sanitize service must be available. Did you include the ngSanitize module as well as the ng-sanitize.js script in your app?