# angularjs to output html clickable element instead of html as a string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using a filter to convert any URL or email id from a piece of content. but its getting rendered as a string not as a clickable HTML element.

**Filter JS**

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).filter('parseUrl', function() {
    var urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
    var emails = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim

    return function(text) {

        if (text.match(urls)) {
            text = text.replace(urls, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>")
        }
        if (text.match(emails)) {
            text = text.replace(emails, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>")
        }

        return text
    }
});
```

this above code output me with a plane text and not clickable HTML elements.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/942RA/152/)**

Comment: alredy asked, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251581/how-to-create-angularjs-filter-which-outputs-html

Comment: or just consult the [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Please check updates. into my question. I have added a fiddle.

Comment: It's better to use `test` than `match` when you just want to check if a pattern exists in a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated [JS Fidle](https://jsfiddle.net/942RA/154/)

HTML: 
Added

> ng-bind-html

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
         <h1 ng-bind-html="test | parseUrl">{{test}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 1):

Your filter should make use of the Strict Contextual Escaping `$sce` to return trusted HTML

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).filter('parseUrl', function ($sce) {
     var urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
     var emails = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim

     return function (text) {
         if (text.match(urls)) {
             text = text.replace(urls, "<a ng-href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
         }

         if (text.match(emails)) {
             text = text.replace(emails, "<a ng-href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
         }

         return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
     }
 });
```

**Update**

It seems your are using an older version of Angular (version 1.0.2) which doesn't have the Strict Contextual Escaping `$sce`. That explains your usage of `ngSanitize` module.

Your filter code is correct, but you should bind your text differently using the `ng-bind-html`.

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
         <h1 ng-bind-html="test | parseUrl"></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fb4meygo/1/

Comment: check my question, I have added fiddle to my question. I tried your solution on local. but no luck....

Answer (score 0):

With the help of linky filter we can detect links from text and show them differently. Linky takes text and produces HTML by wrapping all URLs into anchor tags. It supports email address, http, https, and mailto.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
        <p ng-bind-html="myText | linky :'_blank'"></p>
        <textarea ng-model="myText" style="width: 420px; height: 120px"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "Some default text is here http:/tothenew.com/";
}]);
```