# Is it possible to output html from angular filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made a custom filter it outputs text. However, it puts html as is too. I want it to put html as html not escape it.

If i return html text it get escaped. So is there a way to overcome this.

I have tried `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

My angular version is 1.2.29

Linked answer requires a different approach, the approach that could work doesn't work for some reasons as also noted by others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create angularjs filter which outputs HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251581/how-to-create-angularjs-filter-which-outputs-html)

Comment: i have already left a comment at one of the answers there that this doesn't work

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Have you included `'ngSanitize'` in the dependencies list of your app module?

Comment: Show us the code. We don't know what you are doing or why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your angular if possible. You can use `ng-bind-html` on your element that you wish to show the data. No need for a filter here. `ng-bind-html` will convert text to html and will leave plain text alone.

[AngularJS html binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: ng-bind-html isn't new

Comment: Yes I did because it is good practice. I see how my sentence is worded though, I will fix that.

Comment: the code i am working on belongs to a company i can't simply upgrade it. And opting to not use filter property over ng-bind-html is very big and last choice since the filter is being used all over the place like 30 files.

Comment: I see your dilemma, would you be willing to provide the code to the filter? I would like to look at it to see if I can help.